# what does $('<div/>') do?

Tags: jquery, html

I saw this in jQuery tools in the tooltip script. What is `<div/>` ? I've never seen the backslash used that way. Probably going to get some down votes, but I must know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It used to create a `div` element. Its short cut to `<div></div>`.

For example:

```
$('<div/>', {id: 'hello', 'class': 'new', html: 'New div'}).appendTo('#target');
```

will create div with `id: hello`, `class: new` with html `New div` and append to `#target`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/190/)**

#### More details

It means "create a jQuery-wrapped div element on the fly".

> When the parameter has a single tag, such as `$('<div />')` or
> `$('<a></a>')`, jQuery creates the element using the native JavaScript
> `createElement()` function.

As result it will look like:

```
$(document.createElement("div"));
```

For detail see **[here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)**

Comment: Note that `$('<div>')` would work the same way. In HTML, `<div/>` never creates empty `div` element. You're just relying on the fact that browser would fix the invalid HTML.

Comment: Was waiting on the timer and forgot.