# Explanation needed understanding jQuery objects and offsets

Tags: jquery

So, with `var $moving` we are creating javascript object, right? But what is `$('<li/>')`? It is not even an html element.

Also, offset values describes the values of the `$this` element? So, in this case of the element `#slidingMenu li:first`?

```
var $menu = $("#slidingMenu");
var $selected = $menu.find('li:first');
var $moving   = $('<li/>',{
    className : 'move',
    top       : $selected[0].offsetTop + 'px',
    width     : $selected[0].offsetWidth + 'px'
});
```

Comment: When you do `$('<el>')`, you're creating an element which has been created but not appended to a DOM node. It's the same (more or less) than `var li = document.createElement('li');` It could also be a `documentFragment`, although I don't know explicitly how jQuery handles that in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$("#slidingMenu");` takes the reference of `#slidingMenu` and $('#slidingMenu') returns a jQuery object.
- `$menu.find('li:first');` find the first `li` within the `#slidingMenu`.
- `$moving   = $('<li/>', properties)` means, create a `jQuery-wrapped` `li` element on the fly but not added to DOM. For [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970705/what-does-div-do/10970713#10970713).
- `$selected` is reference to jQuery object and `$selected[0]` gives an element reference/ JavaScript object.But it doesn't means `$selected[0]` is a reference to the first object and `$selected[1]` to the second and so on.

Comment: *... gives an element* reference.

Comment: So, $selected[0] is not a reference to the first object and $selected[1] t othe second?

Answer (score 2):

> So, with `var $moving` we are creating javascript object, right?

No, you're declaring a JavaScript variable that points to an object.

> But what is `$('<li/>')`? It is not even a html element.

It returns a jQuery object. In this particular case, that object contains an HTML element that hasn't yet been appended to the DOM, of the type specified in the first argument (`<li>`) and with the attributes specified in the second argument.

> Also, offset values describes the values of the `$this` element? So, in this case of the element `#slidingMenu li:first`?

Not really sure what you're on about here, there is no `$this` in that code. However, since `$selected` references a jQuery object containing that element, and you're using the `[0]` syntax to get the first (and, as it happens, only) element out of it, yes it does refer to that element.

Comment: Just to make clear (due to the confusion elsewhere), when doing `$sel[0]`, you're getting a DOM node reference, not a jQuery reference. So `$sel[0].text()` won't work, but `$sel[0].id` will, as will (possibly confusing) `$($sel[0]).text()`. I realize you don't get it wrong, but I wanted to state outright what isn't literally said in the last sentence. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery function is heavily overloaded.  This particular overload takes an HTML element `<li>` or `<li />`, followed by a set of properties to set on that element, creates jQuery-wrapped DOM element and sets those properties on it.  Note that setting properties only works if the string contains a single element - `$("<a>text</a><div>otherel</div>", props)` won't work.

On the second point, jQuery wraps DOM elements in its own object, giving you access to its API.  It behaves similarly to an array so `[x]` will get the `x`th element in the set.  `$selected[0]` will get the first (and in this case only) element in the `$selected` set.

Comment: Quibble: It's DOM reference when you access with the `$sel[0]` syntax. See: http://jsfiddle.net/b6SyB/

Comment: @JaredFarrish I said it is a set of DOM elements.

Comment: Emphasis on *quibble*. It's not necessarily real clear that you're getting a DOM node reference back with how it's stated, so it could be expected that `$selected[0].text()` will work. I'm surprised at the number of answers that explicitly got that wrong, I just thought here it was implied correctly but easily confused with the other wrong statements. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

`$('<li/>')` creates an empty dom element with tag `li`. And yes, `$selected[0]` in this case would be the element `#slidingMenu li:first.`

Comment: Technically, it's the DOM reference which evaluates to what `li:first` has referenced. It's not, though, pointing to a jQuery object.